# Why docker rmi -f image just hangs in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

In my Jenkins file, I have 3 stages and at the final image removal stage the build just hangs. I tried adding latest to the image like project-image:latest, still same issue.

Note: this does not happen for all builds as well, just intermittent. Please advice how to avoid this hanging issue.

```
stages {
        stage('Build Docker Container') {
            
            steps {
               
                sh 'docker build -q -f Build_Dockerfile -t project .'
            }
        }

        stage('Run something') {
           
            steps {
                sh ' docker run <somecommand>'
                      
            }
        }
        stage('Remove Docker image') {
           
            steps {
                   sh "docker rmi -f project-image"
                   sh "yes Y | docker image prune"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If image is in use by `docker run` command, you can't delete it.

Comment: As part of docker run command some tests are run and one when it is finished the next command to remove image is called. Still it hangs at this stage like 1 in 5 builds.